# Jquery click event does not execute on first click

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I do not understand why I have to click on the link twice in JQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $("#more_reviewers").click(function(){
        $("#reviewer_list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'restaurants/restaurant_reviewer_list', :venue => @restaurant, :limit => @restaurant.reviews.count) %>");
    });
});
```

When I click, the view overrides the limit on the reviwers shown and shows all the reviewers. What I don't get is why I need to click on the same button twice. None of the other answers to similar questions have worked for me because the problem involves cookie reliance, or somehting else which I'm not doing.

I just tested one more thing: when I put an alert showing the event type, it shows nothing the first time (as if the JS script wasn't bound to the link) then the second time it alerts with the right event type ("click").

The link with ID "more_reviewers" is as follows in rails:

```
<%= link_to "more", "#", :id => "more_reviewers", :remote => true  %>
```

The link shows the right items, but only after being clicked twice (the first time, nothing appears to change on the page)

Help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Is '#more_reviewers' inside an <a> element ?

Comment: Yes @Sagar_Jackey. I edited my question with the link information, here it is for you:

Comment: Remove `:remote => true` from your `link_to`. That's only useful if you want to use Rails' built in functionality for Ajax, but you are writing the Javascript bindings yourself, so it's useless and causes this unwanted effect of having to click twice.

Comment: Hi Mischa thanks for the response. But now the effect without :remote -> true is that a) if I put nothing in the destination part, it reloads the page or b) if I put javascript:void(0) it does nothing.

Comment: Where is this javascript code exactly?

Comment: The controller method is show (this is part of a view to show venue information,among which reviwers). The jquery code is in show.js.erb. In my Controller, I run a format_do block for js and html format, at the end of the controller instructions.

Comment: See my answer. In show.js.erb you should only put the `$("#reviewer_list").html(...)` part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your show.js.erb should only contain:

```
$("#reviewer_list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'restaurants/restaurant_reviewer_list', :venue => @restaurant, :limit => @restaurant.reviews.count) %>");
```

Right now it you're binding a click event to a link you have already clicked, which means you have to click it again.

Comment: OK Mischa, first of all it worked. Thank you. Second, I'm confused. The Show view contains, among other buttons, the "more_reviewers" link. I thought when I load the show view, it also loads all the scripts in show.js.erb. It made sense that I should have an onclick listener (or equivalent) ready to react when there is a click. Here, it seems to me that by clicking on the link I am calling on all the show.js.erb code. What if I had other code not related to the link, say a listener for a click on a different link on the page?

Comment: The reaction is also delayed with this solution. It responds to the click the first time, but the response is slower than after the second click of the previous implementation.  Is this because the entire page is being reloaded remotely?

Comment: No, it does not load show.js.erb. You should only use .js.erb files to return content after an Ajax call. For normal javascript use app/assets/javascripts/applition.js.

Comment: Yes, it's doing an Ajax call, so the response is delayed.

Comment: OK I have one last question: it looks that with this solutoin, if I click on the link, it will launch all the scripts in the .js file. I may have other scripts in the file  (pertaining to a different button for example). How will it tell the difference? How can I solve that problem?

Comment: It seems all that code should be in your application.js file not in show.js.erb. Sorry, but I can give a precise answer, because it's not clear what you are trying to do and I can't see your code.

Comment: I think you've put me on the right track. I transfered my chunk of code to application.js. Only problem is now clicking the link changes the view, but what it shows is the code of the .html instruction in text: `<%= escape_javascript(render "restaurants/restaurant_reviewer_list", :venue => @restaurant, :limit => @restaurant.reviews.count`  This gets rendered literally. If you have a quick fix, it will save me another late night. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well you could put that partial in a hidden div in your view and use `$('#hidden_div').show();` to display it. That kind of stuff should only be in Javascript when you're returning it from a Ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

Just had an issue like this and you should be able to solve it like this (this enables you to do other js stuff in the same file and not in the application.js):

```
$(function(){
  $("#more_reviewers").bind('ajax:complete', function() {
    $("#reviewer_list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'restaurants/restaurant_reviewer_list', :venue => @restaurant, :limit => @restaurant.reviews.count) %>");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove that '#' in your html code. Replace it with `javascript:void(0);`

```
<%= link_to "more", "javascript:void(0);", :id => "more_reviewers", :remote => true  %>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work - the link ceases to respond entirely!

Comment: then try just removing the '#' like this:
`<%= link_to "more", "", :id => "more_reviewers", :remote => true  %>`

Comment: Still the same problem. The click is registered but nothing happens the first time; it does register the click in the browser console. The second time, the click gets registered AND I see the proper behavior on the screen.

Comment: Try this : my first answer without the :remote tag

`<%= link_to "more", "javascript:void(0);", :id => "more_reviewers" %>`

Comment: Hi Sagar just tried that and nothing happens. The link doesn't register a click at all.

Answer (score 0):

This also will work.

```
$("#more_reviewers").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    #.....
});
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out However, this yields the same behavior as before - I need to click twice!

Comment: You want to simply update the **review_list** on clicking that button?   If so, can you try by changing the **link_to** into **button** tag.

Comment: Still the same problem with a button. The click is registered but nothing happens the first time; it does register the click in the browser console. The second time, the click gets registered AND I see the proper behavior on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<%= link_to "more", "", :id => "more_reviewers", :remote => true  %>
```

in my case

```
<%= link_to "more", "#", :id => "more_reviewers", :remote => true  %>
```

works too.

Comment: Hi Shweta, I tried this and obvs it didn't work. Which makes sense becaue the id is a DOM element ID not a param.

Comment: Thanks Shweta. I tried both these solutions (based on other postings) and the problem persists: I always havve to click twice.

Answer (score 0):

In Your Java Script Try including this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.8.3", "jquery.validate" %>
```

I think this will solve your problem as I got solutions using this